# The grid column end is not working when setting height of grid items

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a layout like [image: layout Image], but when I try to create it, I am not getting the layout correctly if I give height to the grid elements.

As per my understanding, grid elements stretch by default to fill in the grid area they are assigned to. Can someone point me in the right direction as to why I am getting this weird behavior?

In dev tools I see message [image: Dev tools image for grid-column-end not applying] [image]

> The display: block property prevents grid-column-end from having an
> effect.

But aren't all the children of a 'Grid' container supposed to be a grid item, and their display property does not matter?

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .container {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: darkslategray;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      gap: 10px;
    }

    .item {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px; /* remove this line and it works */
    }

    .item1 {
      background-color: #0c9e9d;
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 2;
    }

    .item2 {
      background-color: #2ecc71;
      grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 4;
    }

    .item3 {
      background-color: #9b59b6;
      grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5;
    }

    .item4 {
      background-color: #3498db;
      grid-area: 2 / 4 / 4 / 5;
    }

    .item5 {
      background-color: #f1c40f;
    }

    .item6 {
      background-color: #e67e22;
    }

    .item7 {
      background-color: #e74c3c;
    }

    .item8 {
      background-color: lightskyblue;
    }
```

```html
'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
    <div class="item item5"></div>
    <div class="item item6"></div>
    <div class="item item7"></div>
    <div class="item item8"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: *As per my understanding, grid elements stretch by default to fill in the grid area they are assigned to.* --> that's the case when you don't define a height (you already figured out this based on your comment in the code)

Comment: And don't pay attention to the Dev tool warning. It's a new feature that contain a lot of bug and misleading messages. Your code is working fine

Comment: Is there any document defining when it stretches and when it will not? I felt grid containers should not care about heights, as container height is there, and the area has a height, we are telling an item to take up that area. 
Wanted to understand the behaviour.

Comment: an element doesn't take an area. An element is placed within an area and can be sized like any other elements. There no obligation to have the same size as the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: for people coming to this post, there are two things:

1. Grid element do not take up entire space of the grid they are assigned to, they take up the space as per their content or as per the CSS attribute to give then height and width.
2. The Chrome browser message is misleading, and issues are open for that. The elements inside a grid container are Grid children, and they might behave like display blocks or inlines based on grid properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: #0c9e9d;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / span 3 / span 1;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 1 / span 2;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
}

.item4 {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
}

.item5 {
  background-color: #e67e22;
}

.item6 {
  background-color: #3498db;
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / span 2 / span 1;
}

.item7 {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.item8 {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item item1"></div>
    <div class="item item2"></div>
    <div class="item item3"></div>
    <div class="item item4"></div>
    <div class="item item5"></div>
    <div class="item item6"></div>
    <div class="item item7"></div>
    <div class="item item8"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```